# Convergence of the sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let's study the convergence (pointwise and uniform convergence) of of the sequence of functions:
$$
f_n(x)=n^2 \cdot \log{(1+\frac{x}{n})}, \; x\ge0, \; n \in \Bbb N
$$
My attempt:

1. I first study: $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}f_n{(x)}$ for pointwise convergence, and i get:
   $$
   f_n{(x)} \rightarrow 
   \begin{cases}
   0, \; \text{if} \; \;  x=0 \\[2ex]
   +\infty, \; \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
   $$

2. In conclusion, the sequences does not converge: nor pointwisely, neither uniformly.

Although I'm pretty sure of that result (if not I have misunderstood the whole theory), it seems weird to me. Any advices?

Comment: For $[0,\infty)$ you are right. But one may ask on what intervals it converges uniformly.

Comment: Do you mean something such as: $(a, b) \subset [0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, the convergence is uniform in any  bounded interval whose closure does not include $0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. I'll try to trying hardert into!